# Problems linking my files PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem connecting my profile.php

main folder

```
index.php
page1.php
page2.php
page3.php
server folder
css folder
include folder
user folder
```

server folder contains

```
connect.php
```

css folder contains

```
stylesheet.css
```

include folder contains

```
header.php
footer.php
```

user folder contains

```
profile.php
```

all the file have

```
include ROOT.'include/header.php';
include ROOT.'include/footer.php';
```

inside my header.php

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
```

i used

```
chdir('maindirectory');
define('ROOT', getcwd().DS);
```

everything works except my profile.php cant seems to load my css file. The reason why iam separating profile into user because i am using htaccess to remove '.php' and i want to allow user to search through user/'username' as well.

if i never separate, i'll have problems going to other page like `example.com/page2` it will search the user instead of going to page2.

Comment: When you load `profile.php` and the css file doesn't load, have you checked the browsers web inspector to see where the browser is trying (unsuccessfully) to get the css file from? I am not entirely sure from you question but it sounds like because `profile.php` is in the user folder, it is trying to find the css file at `user/css/stylesheet.css` not  `css/stylesheet.css`.

Comment: fixed the problem by using 

href ='/main/css/stylesheet.css/';

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the files using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] instead of ROOT or define ROOT as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use chdir and define to know working folder. You can use __DIR__ constant that returns working directory (see slash before include, __DIR__ don't return last slash):

```
include __DIR__ . '/include/header.php';
include __DIR__ . '/include/footer.php';
```

In profile.php __DIR__ have root/user value. This means that yo need to do:

```
include __DIR__ . '/../include/header.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../include/footer.php';
```

If your version of PHP don't support __DIR__, you can use dirname(__FILE__) instead:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/header.php';
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/footer.php';
```

If you don't know or doubt the directory you are always can echo:

```
echo __DIR__;
```

Comment: You need to know your base url and add to header.php link tag

Comment: thanks! i fixed it with href ='/main/css/stylesheet.css/'